# How to Call RPGIV program from java that returns more than one record

Tags: java, ibm-midrange, rpgle, rpg, jtopen

I am calling a RPGIV program from java, the rpgiv program returnes multi record as an output parameter.

I tried the following to return all the rows returned from rpgiv.

```
   // Define Output Data Structure 
      AS400DataType[] outputData = 
    {
        new AS400Text(20),              // parentOperationsItemId;
        new AS400Text(10),              // parentOperationsItemType;
        new AS400Text(10),              // parentOperationsItemSubType;
        new AS400Text(20),              // parentKnownbyId;
        new AS400Text(10),              // parentInternalStatus;
        new AS400Text(1),               // parentLeafIndicator;
        new AS400Text(20),              // childOperationsItemId;
        new AS400Text(10),              // childOperationsItemType;
        new AS400Text(10),              // childOperationsItemSubType;
        new AS400Text(20),              // childKnownbyId;
        new AS400Text(10),              // childInternalStatus;
        new AS400Text(1),               // childLeafIndicator;
        new AS400Text(10)               // InternalStatus;
    };

AS400Structure [] outputDataConverter2 = new AS400Structure[3];

    outputDataConverter2[0] = new AS400Structure(outputData);
    outputDataConverter2[1] = new AS400Structure(outputData);
    outputDataConverter2[2] = new AS400Structure(outputData);


    Object[] dataInputInformation = 
    {
        sSqlSelect,
        sFetchDirection,
        sOperationsItemId,
        sparentOperationsItemTypeList,
        sparentOperationsItemSubTpeList,
        sparentInternalStatusList,
        schildOperationsItemType,
        schildOperationsItemSubTpeList,
        schildInternalStatusList,
        sLinkStatus
    };


    Object[] dataInputInformationControl = 
    {
        sPosition,
        new BigDecimal(sRowsFetched)
    };


    // Set up the parameter list
    ProgramParameter[] parameterList = new ProgramParameter[4];
    parameterList[0] = new ProgramParameter(7); //ReturnStatus
    parameterList[1] = new ProgramParameter(inputDataConverter.toBytes(dataInputInformation)); //Input
    parameterList[2] = new ProgramParameter(inputDataControlConverter.toBytes(dataInputInformationControl)); //Control
    parameterList[3] = new ProgramParameter(outputDataConverter2[0].getByteLength()*3); //Output



    try 
    {
        // Set the program name and parameter list.
        program.setProgram(programName, parameterList);
        // Run Function
        if (program.run() != true) 
        {
            // Calling Error
            AS400Message[] messagelist = program.getMessageList();
            for (int i = 0; i < messagelist.length; ++i) 
            {
                output[0].ReturnStatus += messagelist[i] + "\n";
            }
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Set the output
            output[0] = new GetPlannedRoute();
            output[1] = new GetPlannedRoute();
            output[2] = new GetPlannedRoute();



            output[0].SetOutput(parameterList, outputDataConverter2[0]);
            output[1].SetOutput(parameterList, outputDataConverter2[1]);
            output[2].SetOutput(parameterList, outputDataConverter2[2]);
        }
    }
```

This is in the output class

```
public void SetOutput(ProgramParameter[] parameterList, AS400Structure outputPlannedRouteConverter) 
    {

        ReturnStatus = P6Entity.CallingRPGFunction.ConvertReturnStatus(parameterList[0]);
        Object[] outputData = (Object[]) outputPlannedRouteConverter.toObject(parameterList[3].getOutputData());
        parentOperationsItemId = ((String) outputData[0]).trim();
        parentOperationsItemType = ((String) outputData[1]).trim();
        parentOperationsItemSubType = ((String) outputData[2]).trim();
        parentKnownbyId = ((String) outputData[3]).trim();
        parentInternalStatus = ((String) outputData[4]).trim();
        parentLeafIndicator = ((String) outputData[5]).trim();

        childOperationsItemId = ((String) outputData[6]).trim();
        childOperationsItemType = ((String) outputData[7]).trim();
        childOperationsItemSubType = ((String) outputData[8]).trim();
        childKnownbyId = ((String) outputData[9]).trim();
        childInternalStatus = ((String) outputData[10]).trim();
        childLeafIndicator = ((String) outputData[11]).trim();

        InternalStatus = ((String) outputData[12]).trim();
    }
```

I am not sure how to define parameterList[3] to be able to receive multiple rows back or multiple data structures. And how to get a specific instance of the output parameterList[3].

The RPGIV code:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a29wf1ft0f07sx1/functionCode.txt?dl=0

The  * FetchedData Occures OCCURS(64) INZ is the output data set that I want to return to java.

Comment: Does the RPG program really return multiple records?  Is it returning a result set?  Or is it an array?  Please edit your question to include the RPG parameter list.

Comment: @BuckCalabro I added the source of the rpgiv parameters, the FetchedData Occurs 64 is what I am trying to return.

Comment: What I also see is that It always returns only the first record.

Comment: I don't see any parameter definitions in the RPG source nor is there any code that populates a return parameter, so it's hard to be sure about anything. However, you are defining a multi-occurence data structure; and you probably should be using an array of DSs instead.

Comment: @user2338816 Do I need to post the whole source of the function in rpgiv? And Do you mean I need to use an array in java? DS? Do you have an example maybe?

Comment: I know that the function in RPGIV is returning more than one record, when I call it via another rpgiv function I can process the data. I think its to do on the java side with parameter3.

Comment: I am an RPG programmer and when the Java people want 'multiple records' I return a result set to them.  A multi-occurrence data structure like V00001 is like a two dimensional array that is contiguous in memory.  If I guessed right at the parameter list (which isn't shown) RPG is returning 9728 bytes, broken up as 64 separate 152 byte structures.

Comment: @Renier Seeing the prototypes used on both the RPG and Java sides would be necessary at a minimum. The whole function source shouldn't be needed, but additional sections might be requested.

Comment: @BuckCalabro thanks I did not know that, could you please look at the source code I included a link to the full source. Do you maybe have an example how to read the output in Java? Maybe I am using the wrong code ?

Comment: @user2338816 I have included a link to the source in RPG please can you look at it.

Comment: It seems that program 'YOBCPYDS' is actually responsible for ensuring the returned values, so we'd also need to see what it does with V00001 and V00002. Because both of those are multi-occurrence data structures (MODS) rather than arrays, their **basic** definitions are CHAR(152) rather than (9728). That is, they are defined with the older OCCURS() keyword rather than DIM(). As such, it can often take a step or two of extra care to return an entire set rather than only a single 'occurrence'. Also, the Java prototype is still needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited to show how to convert a packed value.

Let's cut this down a bit.  Here is a small RPG program that has a similar structure to yours:

```
 D V00001          DS                  OCCURS(64)
 D  F0000G                       20A
 D  F0000H                       10A
 D  F0000I                       10A
 D  F0000J                       20A
 D  F0000K                        9p 0
 D  F0000L                        1A
 D  F0000M                       20A
 D  F0000N                       10A
 D  F0000O                       10A
 D  F0000P                       20A
 D  F0000Q                       10A
 D  F0000R                        1A
 D  F0000S                       10A

 c     *entry        plist
 c                   parm                    v00001

   // populate the first entry
   %occur(v00001) = 1;
   F0000G = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000H = *ALL'A';
   F0000I = *ALL'B';
   F0000J = *ALL'C';
   F0000K = 123456789;
   F0000L = *ALL'E';
   F0000M = *ALL'F';
   F0000N = *ALL'G';
   F0000O = *ALL'H';
   F0000P = *ALL'I';
   F0000Q = *ALL'J';
   F0000R = *ALL'K';
   F0000S = *ALL'a';

   // populate the 2nd entry
   %occur(v00001) = 2;
   F0000G = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000H = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000I = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000J = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000K = 200;
   F0000L = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000M = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000N = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000O = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000P = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000Q = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000R = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000S = *ALL'b';

   // populate the third entry
   %occur(v00001) = 3;
   F0000G = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000H = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000I = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000J = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000K = 300;
   F0000L = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000M = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000N = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000O = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000P = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000Q = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000R = *ALL'1234567890';
   F0000S = *ALL'c';

   // reset back to the beginning
   %occur(v00001) = 1;
   dump(a);

   *inlr = *on;
```

Here is the Java (I AM NOT A Java PROGRAMMER!) that successfully reads the various 'records':

```
public String testSO(AS400 system, String programName) {
    boolean success = false;
    final int ONE_ROW_LEN = 147;
    final int DS_ROWS = 64;
    AS400Text dsText = new AS400Text(ONE_ROW_LEN * DS_ROWS);
    AS400Text p0000g = new AS400Text(20);
    AS400Text p0000h = new AS400Text(10);
    AS400Text p0000i = new AS400Text(10);
    AS400Text p0000j = new AS400Text(20);
    int p0000k;  // packed(9, 0) is 5 bytes
    AS400Text p0000l = new AS400Text( 1);
    AS400Text p0000m = new AS400Text(20);
    AS400Text p0000n = new AS400Text(10);
    AS400Text p0000o = new AS400Text(10);
    AS400Text p0000p = new AS400Text(20);
    AS400Text p0000q = new AS400Text(10);
    AS400Text p0000r = new AS400Text( 1);
    AS400Text p0000s = new AS400Text(10);
    String ds = null;

    String returnString = null;

    try
    {
        ProgramCall program = new ProgramCall(system);

        // Set up the parameter list
        ProgramParameter[] parameterList = new ProgramParameter[1];
        parameterList[0] = new ProgramParameter(ONE_ROW_LEN * DS_ROWS); 
        program.setProgram(programName, parameterList);
        success = program.run();

        if(success!=true){
            AS400Message[] messagelist = program.getMessageList();
            System.out.println("\nMessages received:\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < messagelist.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(messagelist[i]);
            }
        } else {
            // RPG is returning a giant chunk of memory
            //allBytes = parameterList[0].getOutputData();
            ds = (String)dsText.toObject(parameterList[0].getOutputData());
            System.out.println("ds=" + ds);
            System.out.println("ds len=" + ds.length());

            // Need to index our way into the block of memory
            // zero-based!
            int row = 0;
            int x = row * ONE_ROW_LEN;
            System.out.println("x=" + x);

            // parse out the individual elements for this row
            int len = p0000g.getByteLength();
            String s0000g = ds.substring(x, x+len);
            x += len;
            len = p0000h.getByteLength();
            String s0000h = ds.substring(x, x+len);
            x += len;
            len = p0000i.getByteLength();
            String s0000i = ds.substring(x, x+len);
            x += len;
            len = p0000j.getByteLength();
            String s0000j = ds.substring(x, x+len);

        // this is packed(9, 0)
        x += len;
        len = 5;
        byte[] b0000k = dsText.toBytes(ds.substring(x, x+len));
        BigDecimal d0000k = (BigDecimal)new AS400PackedDecimal(9, 0).toObject(b0000k);
        p0000k = d0000k.intValue();
        String s0000k = d0000k.toString();

            x += len;
            len = p0000l.getByteLength();
            String s0000l = ds.substring(x, x+len);
            x += len;
            len = p0000m.getByteLength();
            String s0000m = ds.substring(x, x+len);
            x += len;
            len = p0000n.getByteLength();
            String s0000n = ds.substring(x, x+len);
            x += len;
            len = p0000o.getByteLength();
            String s0000o = ds.substring(x, x+len);
            x += len;
            len = p0000p.getByteLength();
            String s0000p = ds.substring(x, x+len);
            x += len;
            len = p0000q.getByteLength();
            String s0000q = ds.substring(x, x+len);
            x += len;
            len = p0000r.getByteLength();
            String s0000r = ds.substring(x, x+len);
            x += len;
            len = p0000s.getByteLength();
            String s0000s = ds.substring(x, x+len);


            returnString = s0000s;
            System.out.println("Return=" + returnString);
            System.out.println("g=" + s0000g);
            System.out.println("h=" + s0000h);
            System.out.println("i=" + s0000i);
            System.out.println("i=" + s0000i);
            System.out.println("j=" + s0000j);
            System.out.println("k=" + s0000k);
            System.out.println("l=" + s0000l);
            System.out.println("m=" + s0000m);
            System.out.println("n=" + s0000n);
            System.out.println("o=" + s0000o);
            System.out.println("p=" + s0000p);
            System.out.println("q=" + s0000q);
            System.out.println("r=" + s0000r);
            System.out.println("r=" + s0000s);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("\ne:\n");
        System.out.println(e);
        System.out.println("\nStack trace:\n");
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    return returnString;
}
```

The key part to understand in the Java are that with this design, Parameter.getOutputData() is returning byte[].  I am not a Java programmer, so my Java code is ugly.  I cast the returned byte[] to String and assigned it as a block to ds.  I then brute-forced a section of code that substrings out the individual variables one by one.  If I knew more Java I'd probably have put that junk in a constructor and maybe exposed it as a List.

Having posted all that, there is no way I would operate this way with production code.  I would have the IBM programmers write me a wrapper around the SuperUltimateBlockFetch - that wrapper would call SuperUltimateBlockFetch and build a result set for use by Java.  They could even make it into a stored procedure.  This would decouple your dependence on understanding the internals of how the RPG structure is built and make it much more natural to deal with the individual variables in the Java code.  Then all you would do would be to call the stored procedure and write a `while rs.next()` loop.

Comment: Thanks I did not know that it would be one block of data in bytes. Thanks for you help I can at least see all the data in the returning string.

Comment: In your example you use AS400Text p0000g = new AS400Text(20); as one of your output fields and it works with the substring to get the correct value. In one of my examples I have a AS400PackedDecimal ContactID = new AS400PackedDecimal(9,0); Defined as one of my output fields but when casting it to the String to substring it it returns funny data.. How would one process a AS400PackedDecimal(9,0)?

Comment: You said that Parameter.getOutputData() is returning byte[].So is there a way to get the bytes of AS400PackedDecimal(9,0) field and then convert it to a int? And how? or am I on the wrong track?

Comment: I edited the code to show how I converted a packed value to int.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you not try to pass the data as parameters.

Instead, use a data queue to pass the data back.

Have the java program create a data queue and pass it's name to the RPG program as a parameter.

The RPG program would then send the data to the queue using the [QSNDDTAQ](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_i5_54/apis/qsnddtaq.htm) API.

When control returns to the Java program, have it read the entries from the [data queue](http://javadoc.midrange.com/jtopen/com/ibm/as400/access/DataQueue.html).

Comment: Data queues ARE another good idea.  It looks like the RPG program is generated with Cool:Plex/2E so any change to the RPG side is probably going to require a wrapper rather than touch the generated code.